# Not able to launch my Xcode 13.4.1 generated app on my real device iPhone 13 Pro Max

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, xcode13

I am new to iPhone app development and I want to launch my React Native iOS app on my real device but I am getting unable to install "myapp".

I have added my device UDID on appstore. I got it through https://udid.tech/

I checked the details and this is what I got:

```
Unable to install "myapp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-07-26 21:34:14 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
```

It says:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

**My Xcode 13.4.1 signing configuration looks like this:**

Targets: **myapp**

[image]

Targets: **myappTests**

[image]

I followed [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device) and many other resources but no luck.

Please help me out with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long hard struggle. I managed to make it work.

In my scheme definition it was set to "Release".

Goto Products > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Change to "Debug"

Answer (score -1):

I know the reason of this issue, Please add the team which have developer console account, not add the custom created team if u have to run on the real device

Comment: Take a look at the images I shared. The team is selected there for this project. That was not the issue actually. Everything is already configured correctly. I needed to change Scheme to debug. Previously It was set to release.